# prevent scroll on body when disclosure panel is open

Tags: reactjs, next.js, headless-ui

I'm using headless uis Disclosure to open a sidemenu. In a <Disclosure.Panel> I use "overflow-auto" to enable scrolling in the menu. However I want to disable the scroll on Body when I do this since otherwise I have two scrollbars for the y axis. Any tips on how to achieve this?

Comment: Your problem is probably related to incorrect styles. You would need to create a minimal example, but I guess that setting constant height or width on the menu would help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Target the `<body>` or `<html>` element on the page and add `overflow: hidden` to prevent scrolling on the X or Y axis. You can do this with a class and toggle the class on when the panel is open and off when its closed to allow scrolling again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your input David, I know this is how it works normally, however in my case, I have this as a component that I then add into _app, so I cannot target the full body from the component.

Comment: Can you track the state of the panel (open or closed) from app and pass the function to update the state to the  <Disclosure.Panel> so it can update the state value and then in app handle the css?